# The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query RX

Tags: system.reactive

Consider this in a test SL app (trying to learn RX):

```
var input = (from _ in Observable.FromEventPattern(txt, "TextChanged")
                     select txt.Text)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.05)).DistinctUntilChanged();

        var svc = new DictServiceSoapClient();

        var res = from term in input
                  from words in svc.MatchInDictAsync("wn", term, "prefix")
                  select words;
```

The "from" in "from words in svc...." shows the error message:  "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query.  Try..."

I don't get what it is trying to say. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not know what type of observable 'FromEventPattern' will return since that method uses reflection to get the event.  You need to help it out by telling it what type of object is returned by the event:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged")
```